# Order Association by other Association from Mapping - Doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

This works **Ordering To-Many Associations**

```
/** @Entity **/
class User
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
     **/
    private $groups;
}
```

But if in my **Group** Entity I have an `To-One association` (therefore a `foreign_key field`), I can't order by foreign_key field:

```
/** @Entity **/
class Group
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Auxiliar", inversedBy="groups", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="auxiliar_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $auxiliar;
}
```

Why can't I order the groups by `auxiliar_id`? This doesn't work (`500: unrecognized field`):

```
/** @Entity **/
class User
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"auxiliar_id" = "ASC"})
     **/
    private $groups;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Also tried: `auxiliar`, `groups.auxiliar`, `groups.auxiliar_id`, `auxiliar.id`

Comment: Tried `{"auxiliar" = "ASC"}`? Wihtout `_id`.

Comment: @Narek - Yes `auxiliar`, `groups.auxiliar`, `groups.auxiliar_id`, `auxiliar.id` :| The same unrecognized field 500 error

Comment: So if you remove ` * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Auxiliar", inversedBy="groups", fetch="EAGER")` it will work like `name` field? Try, if it not work then problem in other place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `auxiliar_id` field inside the `Group` entity and it will be filled by doctrine after hydration.